# How to use Office 365 Enterprise apps for another account in family e.g. for kids?

Tags: office365

I have Office 365 Enterprise work account with 5 possible installations.
I need to install it for kids without them having access to my work account.
How can I do that?
Whenever I logout from my Office 365 Eneterprise account on their laptops, the license disappears and is no longer available until I login again. I need to logoff - to disable access to company data - but leave the enterprise licence on the PC available for kids.

Comment: The five installs are all for **you** on different machines, not for anyone else. They will need to set up their own subscriptions.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have asked 3 IT guys from my company and they said that it is possible and I have done this few years ago, is it some recent change in license conditions?

Comment: No, this is how Office 365 Enterprise has always worked. The most likely scenario is that the IT guys did _not_ log off. // Get Office 365 Home if you need to supply multiple users. It can be shared with up to 5 other Microsoft accounts.

Comment: It may have worked before the 365 structure, but that is now tied to the person not the machine, unlike MS's regular policy. You need subscriptions per user [as they cannot be added to your company's structure for obvious reasons]

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin, *enterprise* account installs are likely the problem. Normally for a "personal" account you would go to https://account.microsoft.com/services/microsoft365/details and share the subscription to members of your family group. I doubt this is possible if the subscription is being shared to you via an enterprise licence.

Comment: Thanks, it worked few years ago that kids could work in Office 365 Enterprise after I logged off but now on Windows 11(?) it has changes and seems indeed impossible.

Comment: （Possibly redundant）Microsoft 365 Apps is licensed on a "per user" basis.

Answer (score 0):

It's 5 installations per user. As they are different users, this isn't what you are licensed for, which is why you are struggling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).